# Text-to-speech program that allows controlling the reading speed

Tags: speech-synthesis

I need a text-to-speech program.  I am planning to use this software for proofreading purposes therefore understandable quality is enough for my purposes. There is a [similar question here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/high-quality-text-to-speech-converter/1491#1491) but I do not need sound file or other features of suggested program.

Ideally it should have following features:

- Able to read English.
- Able to read txt files.
- Able to read other formats like PDF, DOC, DOCX, EPUB, ….
- Has a speed option to control reading speed.
- Windows 8 support or Mac OS or Linux.
- Ideally free software.

Actually the old [Microsoft Reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reader) has some of these features, but it is not available for Windows 8.

Answer (score 4):

On **OS X**, there's already a text-to-speech utility integrated with the OS. You can simply use the **`say`** command from a terminal like this:

```
say "Hello World"
```

or with text from a **file**:

```
say -f mytext.txt
```

Use the `-v` option to choose a different **voice**:

```
say -v Agnes "Hello World"
```

The **reading speed** and default voice can be configured in `System Preferences -> Speech`:

[image: Text to Speech Preferences]

If you check the `[x] Speak selected text when the key is pressed` option, you can select text from any application and have it spoken by using that keyboard shortcut.

So while the command line `say` utility only supports plain text directly, you can get it to speak selected text in any format using the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

The Edge browser has free (very high quality) TTS integrated and over 300 different voices + adjustable speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Intelligent Speaker](https://intelligent-speaker.com) - extension for Google Chrome. You can open your text in browser and listen it. Speech rate is adjustable. I am the author.

Answer (score 0):

I programmed the Windows app [Select to Speak](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/select-to-speak-beta/9PFB0W8KV1ZJ) for this purpose.
It can read out loud every selected text and is therefore program or file independent.
You can contact me for a free version or if you have issues or missing a feature.

> To answerer your question in detail. It is able to: 
>  - read English (or any other installed Language)
>  - read text from txt, PDF, DOC or anything else where you can select the text
>  - to speed up the reading
>  - windows support
>  - contact me for a free version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).