# Text-to-Speech with Announcer Voice

Tags: speech-synthesis

My question is related to these two questions:

1. [High quality text-to-speech converter](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/high-quality-text-to-speech-converter)
2. [text-to-speech program?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/text-to-speech-program)

I would like a program that can translate text to speech like those 2 questions, but I would like the output to be in an Announcer Voice (the kind you hear at a sporting event). Most of the traditional text to speech programs only give you an output in a boring computerized voice that can be very hard to listen to.

Some of the newer programs have more life-like voices, but they still aren't very good.