# Program to convert document to .mp3 file

Tags: windows-7, osx, document-converter, speech-synthesis, mp3

Is there a program to convert a document (formats below) to an audio file (formats below)?

I need:

- it to be <£20 (preferably free)
- it to convert from .doc, .docx, .pdf, and .txt (txt is optional)
- it to produce a .mp3 and .wav file
- run on Windows 7 64 bit and, preferably OSX 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)
- it to have an English UK accent with male and female voices

Comment: How about [text-to-speech program](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4502/903)?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Kind of - but I just want to browse for a file, and automatically get an mp3 file (or wav) outputted - nothing else, nothing less :)

Comment: Makes sense, sounds good :)

Answer (score 1):

On OSX, you can select text, right click the selection, and choose "Add to iTunes as a Spoken Track." From there you can view the sound file in finder and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Looks like you must select text to do this! Do you know of any solutions by just using the file? Sorry for the *extremely* late reply!