# Is there any Text-to-Speech engine that sounds credibly human?

Tags: speech-synthesis

I'm just wondering if there's any **TTS engine** that may be trained with reading control sentences on the correct pronunciation and expression of words.

The end goal being a voice that doesn't sound simulated or robotic.

If you don't know of any, do you know why they don't exist?

Edit: Ideally it would be **English,** free, but up to 100 AUD would be acceptable and operating **Windows or Linux**.

Current programs I'm aware of include: **Textaloud**, **NaturalReader** and online **Ivona** and **Acapela-group**.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1491/10345

Comment: So you want to train the computer by talking into a microphone yourself? Why do you think your pronunciation is perfect ;-) I know it's possible to create a voice from spoken input. Getting that done is a tedious process offered by commercial providers and it'll require ~100 hours of speech for high quality. But still, this will not improve the pronunciation, since the pronunciation is taken from the written text. Only a good dictionary behind may solve this issue, which always leaves you with new unknown words that are not pronunced correctly.

Comment: Aside from my last comment, have a look at http://www.acapela-group.com/. They have lots of English voices and they're really becoming fantastic, especially the emotional ones. You can [report pronunciation bugs](https://acapela-box.com/AcaBox/index.php) and they have a tool "DicoEdit" that allows you to add phonemes to the dictionary

Comment: I was already aware of Ivona, and wasn't really sure if it was what I was after.

Comment: Ideally yes, I would like to train the program to an Australian accent, there don't seem to be any decent replications of the accent out there. Otherwise with any of the programs e.g. Text aloud, acapela group, Ivona etc. is it possible to edit the dictionary and phonemes yourself? I know the acapela online you said can.